# Why this Bash regex does not work?

Tags: regex, bash

Why following regex does not match?

```
dev="$1"
regex="[a-zA-z]+([0-9]+)"
echo $dev
if [[ "$dev" =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "Got a match: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "Could not craete routing table reference due to incorrect device name [$dev]"
fi
```

This gives me the output

```
tun0
Could not craete routing table reference due to incorrect device name [tun0]
```

Same regex in some online test tool works fine eg. http://regexraptor.net/

Bash version `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: You should know that the `[...]` is a *bracket expression* that contains (in your case) ranges of *collating elements* that are locale-dependent. To disable the locale dependency you may add a `export LC_ALL=C` line on top and your regex will "work" the way you defined. However, `A-z` in this case will be matching more than you need (`[`, ``\``, `]`, and some more).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the lower case of `Z`.

So should it be:

```
regex="[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+)"
```

and not `[a-zA-z]+([0-9]+)` like you have it.

**Update. Why is [A-z] invalid?**

Why is the regex `[A-z]` invalid?

It is not always so. It depends on the sort order of the characters: if `A` is greater than `z` or not?
The order is configured with LC_COLLATE.

Compare that:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C bash -c '[[ a =~ [A-z] ]] ; echo $?'
0
$ bash -c '[[ a =~ [A-z] ]] ; echo $?'
2
```

If you set `LC_COLLATE` to `C` (switch locale off), then characters sorted by their ASCII codes and `z` is greater than `A`. Otherwise (it depends on your locale settings) `A` is greater than `A` and the regexp is incorrect hence exit code 2.

Comment: @Antoniossss: That's right :) But we've solved it

Comment: Will accept answer in asap. Thank you

Comment: @Antoniossss: Thank you!

Comment: It would be a great plus if you could answer the question *Why this Bash regex does not work?*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew He did exactly that? o.ô

Comment: @Seth: There is no explanation why `A-z` is invalid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, right. My bad.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: fixed, see my update

Comment: @seth: Fixed, see my update